# Parameters in FeedBurner feeds

Tags: rss, feedburner

I've got an RSS feed for a site which I pass through [FeedBurner](http://www.feedburner.com/). I now want to add a feed for search results, which would mean potentially infinite feed URLs: http://site.com/rss?q=foo, http://site.com/rss?q=bar etc.

Is it possible to set up FeedBurner to handler parameters, or to programmatically add feeds to FeedBurner?